# Adding in a parameter in the initialization stage

Tags: python, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am trying to add a parameter, `state` in the `__init__` of my dialog as follows:

```
class dialog_test(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, state, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog Testing')
        self.setModal(False)
        self.state = state
        if self.state == "stack":
            # Run the function if the state is stack
        if self.state == "user":
            # Run the function if the state is user

        ...

def open_dialog():
    current_selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if len(current_selection) == 1 and cmds.nodeType(current_selection) == 'stack':
        check_for_nodes = main_code.get_nodes_in_scene()
        state = "stack"
    elif len(current_selection) > 1:
        for items in current_selection:
            if not 'Stack' in cmds.nodeType(items):
                state = "user"
            else:
                cmds.warning("Please reselect")
                return

    dialog = dialog_test(state)
    dialog.show()
    return dialog
```

First, is this the correct way to do so, feels very hacky to me and will it have any issues?
I asked because I am still be using `state` in my latter part of the code

Comment: it is standard method to add parameter.

Comment: don't ask two different question - create new  thread. Besides first try your code, later ask question.

Comment: @furas So I removed my second question. In any case, I have tried out my code, it does seems to work initially then it is not, also I am not sure if this is the correct approach to do so